# Trinity Helper (Renderer)

Tags: security, wallet

Previously, I have had no problem opening Trinity on my Mac and after providing my password, it opened correctly. I updated after the recent closure and again, all was satisfactory. I have not used IOTA for a while, but I attempted to open it yesterday and received a message "Trinity Helper (Renderer) wants confidential info from my Trinity Wallet in my keychain and requires "login" keychain password. The only key I originally had was the one given to me for the seed vault, but this password was not accepted. If I click on "Deny" in this box a page opens stating error opening Trinity and now I cannot access IOTA. Any suggestions as to why this message is now appearing and how to resolve the issue.

Comment: never used Trinity on a mac, but I experienced similar messages on a Mac when changing my mac password. Entering your old mac password may get you past that prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enter the password of your mac. Keychain is apple's tool for accessing password info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem as Roger on my mac. It won't accept my password when prompted by Trinity Helper (Renderer). I'm wondering if this problem will be solved when firefly wallet comes into effect. Surprising how little information is out there to address this problem.